# Why ftp credentials are stripped away from email body when using MailMessage in C#?

Tags: c#, smtpclient, ftp-client

I am dispatching emails at clients, notifying them for specific content deliveries and I have a problem with the containing ftp uri in mail body. I am constructing the ftp uri alongside with ftp credentials in the following format, but the credentials part is stripped away (the section user:pass@):

ftp://user:pass@server/relativepath/filename

The code is something like that:

```
mailTemplate += String.Format("<a href=\"{0}\">File FTP URI: {1}</a><br>",
    new Uri(ftpBaseLink, filename), filename);
```

and the email is dispatched with the following matter:

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(
    mailSettings.Smtp.From,
    mailTo,
    subject,
    mailMessage) { IsBodyHtml = true };
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();               
client.Send(message);
```

Is there any clue how can I override this "normalization"?

Comment: Can you get the raw email?  My guess is that MailMessage is not stripping them, but that the receiving email server is.

Comment: You are right, I was using (as a test email) a windows live account. I have just tested it with another email and it worked!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* that there was a general "tightening" of security a while back because of the way URLs containing user:pass were being mis-used to fool people into thinking they were clicking on a link to `http://www.mybank.com` when the link itself was `http://www.mybank.com:blah@www.adodgysite.com/fake_bank_site`. Users are wiser now, but it may be that its this "lockdown" that is affecting you.

My suggestion would be to concatenate the URI yourself, without using `Uri`

Comment: In debugging mode the mailTemplate variable, has the well-formed ftp uri (with credentials).

Answer (score 0):

off the top, i'd look into what 'new Uri(ftpBaseLink, filename)' becomes as a string.